# Union and order by a column not selected

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table A, with columns a_1 and a_2.

I am only interested in the column `a_1`, so I can write something like this :

```
select a_1 from A;
```

However I want it ordered by column `a_2`, so I could write this :

```
select a_1 from A order by a_2 desc;
```

Now I want to do an union :

```
select a_1 from A where <some filters>
union
select a_1 from A where <some other filters>
order by a_2 desc;
```

This doesn't work anymore (`"a_2": invalid identifier`), so I change it to :

```
select a_1, a_2 from A where <some filters>
union
select a_1, a_2 from A where <some other filters>
order by a_2 desc;
```

The `select a_2` part bothers me : I don't want it to show in the results, how can I hide this information ?

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, it doesn't make sense to `order by a_2` after you've done a `union` on just `a_1`.  From Oracle's perspective, it is entirely possible that for any distinct `a_1` value in either query, there may be many different `a_2` values returned.  So there are many possible sort orders.

You can, of course, nest the query so that you only get `a_1` in the results

```
select a_1
  from (select a_1, a_2 from A where <some filters>
        union
        select a_1, a_2 from A where <some other filters>) sub_q
 order by a_2 desc;
```

Of course, from a performance standpoint, it would make sense to use `union all` rather than `union` unless you really do want the look for and eliminate duplicate rows.  And if both queries are really pulling from the same table, it probably makes more sense to use a single query with an `or` rather than writing a `union` of two different queries.

Answer (score 1):

Say that the `UNION` on both columns produce:

```
a_1 a_2
  A   1
  A   3
  B   2
```

Then `UNION` on only a_1 gives

```
 a_1
   A
   B
```

How do you know where to put A according to column a_2's values 1 and 3?

When `UNION` (or `DISTINCT`), only selected columns are allowed in the `ORDER BY`!

However, some dbms products allow non-selected columns when `UNION ALL`!